# ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC : wrap responses

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an application developed in ASP.NET Core MVC with a set of controllers for normal view responses and Web API.

I am trying to figure a correct way to wrap all Web API responses with a consistent class.

My first question is what would be a correct approach to wrap the responses coming from Web API controllers. Since I have two controller types, I would need to distinguish between them as the responses should only be wrapped for API controller, and not view controllers.

As I understand there are two choices a middleware or an action filter.

At first I thought the middleware would be the best choice, but then I realized that I would still need to figure out what kind of request is being processed which would add more potential headache with maintenance?

Then I looked at an action filter and it seems that it would be a better choice to plugin the wrapping handling.

For example an action filter can be added to a base controller just for Web API and not controllers handling the views.

So the question is whether the action filters are best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to look at [result filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#result-filters) for this. Result filters run after a controller action has produced a result, and it allows you to look at that result and then perform some action.

For example, when you return `View` in a controller action, then what gets returned is a [`ViewResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2) which makes it easy to identify results that would cause a Razor view to be rendered.

Within an API controller, you would usually return a [`ActionResult<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2), some model object directly, or an [`ObjectResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.objectresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2). The former two will be automatically converted into an `ObjectResult` as the action gets executed. So you can just look for `ObjectResult`s and then change the result to have some wrapper object instead. This would look something like this:

```
public class WrapApiResponseResultFilter : IResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        var result = context.Result;
        if (result is ObjectResult)
        {
            // wrap the inner object
            var newValue = new WrapperObject(result.Value);

            // replace the result
            context.Result = new ObjectResult(newValue)
            {
                // copy the status code
                StatusCode = result.StatusCode,
            };
        }
    }

    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    { }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, thanks a lot! Will be looking at result filters.