# Net Core: Wrap DTO in Response Pattern in Dynamic Variable Way

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, request-response

Software requirements is asking all DTOs contain their own Response Class. So developers basically wrap Product DTO in Base Response class. We have whole list of class areas, requiring hundreds of classes for Product, Sales, Customer, etc all doing same thing, per below. Client does not want to wrap as `BaseResponse<Product> or BaseResponse<IEnumerable<ProductDto>` since it is nested/unreadable.

Is there method to wrap/create variable classes and readable,  without manually writing 100s of class (maybe extension method, dynamic class, variable, not sure, open to any method)?

Note:  Response classes can be different, so want to give programmer option to create automated  standard class, or create own customized manual class, so two options can exist.

**Current Code:**

**Product DTO Class:**

```
public class ProductDto
{
    public int ProductId { get; set;},
    public string ProductName { get; set;},
    public string ProductDescription { get; set;},
    public float SalesAmount { get; set;}
}
```

**BaseResponse:**

```
public class BaseResponse<T>
{
    [Required, ValidateObject]
    public T Body { get; set; }
    public bool HasError { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
}
```

**Individual Response:**

```
public class GetAllProductResponse : BaseResponse<IEnumerable<ProductDto>>
{
}

public class GetProductResponse : BaseResponse<ProductDto>
{
}

public class UpdateProductResponse : BaseResponse<ProductDto>
{
}
```

**Proposed Code:**

```
public static class ResponseExtensions
{
    public static BaseRequestResponse<T> GetAllResponse<T> (this T obj) where T:class
    {
        return BaseRequestResponse<IEnumerable<T>>;
    }

    public static BaseRequestResponse<T> GetResponse<T>(this T obj) where T : class
    {
        return BaseRequestResponse<T>;
    }

    public static BaseRequestResponse<T> UpdateResponse<T>(this T obj) where T : class
    {
        return BaseRequestResponse<T>;
    }
}
```

So the code will now look as this,

```
ProductDTO.GetAllResponse
ProductDTO.GetResponse
ProductDTO.UpdateResponse
```

Is this a good method, architecturally sound, or should something else be applied?
This probably will not work, since any middle tier layer sending/receiving response will need refer to as BaseResponse< IEnumerable< ProductDto >, etc.

By the way,if going this route, receiving compilation error here

```
'BaseRequestResponse<T>' is a type, which is not valid in the given context
```

**Update:**
This is how we use DTO and Response

```
public async Task<ActionResult<GetProductResponse>> GetByProduct(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var productdto = await productAppService.GetProductById(id);
        var response = new GetProductResponse { Body = productdto };
        return Ok(response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
        var response = new GetDocumentResponse { HasError = true, Error = ex.Message };
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you actually need your controllers to mention those specific types, a more flexible solution would be to use [result filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#result-filters). Result filters run after the controller action and allow you to transform and replace the result that waas produced.

I’ve covered the implementation of this idea in this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57944969/216074).

You can then apply that filter, e.g. using a `[TypeFilter]` attribute:

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(ApiResultFilter))]
public ActionResult<ProductDto> GetProduct(int id)
{
    //
    return product;
}
```

This also works as an attribute on the controller, to apply it to all actions of the decorated controller.

Or apply it globally for all action results by configuring it in your `Startup`:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new ApiResultFilter());
});
```

---

Regarding your error, the extensions you wrote just do `return SomeType`. But you will actually have to create your `BaseResponse<T>` type and place the result object into it, e.g.:

```
public static BaseRequestResponse<T> GetResponse<T>(this T obj) where T : class
{
    return new BaseRequestResponse<T>()
    {
        Body = obj,
    };
}
```

---

In regards to your “DTO and response” example you posted, that’s exactly what you would use result filters for. The idea is to make controller actions as concrete as possible. Any boilerplate stuff should be extracted into filters that can be reused. So the final action may look like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Product>> GetByProduct(int id)
{
    return await productAppService.GetProductById(id);
}
```

You would then use a [result filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#result-filters) to wrap that product with your wrapper type, and use [exception filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#exception-filters) to handle exceptions to return a custom error response object instead.

Comment: thanks, I will check it out, just curious how I will take the DTORequestClass  DTOResponseClass and send it to the application service layer methods,

Comment: by the way, is this typical strategy to use ResultFilters with a request response architectural pattern?

Comment: I think you maybe right, I posted  our implementation above dto and response above, feel free to add anything further, I'll have to read if ActionFilter is consistent with Request/Response pattern, thanks !

Comment: I’ve added another section to my answer that expands on your example code. Basically, the idea is to remove any boilerplate stuff from controller actions. You can use filters for this. And yeah, I would say that this is a very typical approach, and the framework already does a lot like this itself. So you are only expanding on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should Return Object of BaseRequestResponse type.

```
public static class ResponseExtensions
{
    public static BaseRequestResponse<T> GetAllResponse<T> (this T obj) where T:class
    {
        return //should return a object instade of type 
    }

    public static BaseRequestResponse<T> GetResponse<T>(this T obj) where T : class
    {
        return //should return a object instade of type 
    }

    public static BaseRequestResponse<T> UpdateResponse<T>(this T obj) where T : class
    {
        return //should return a object instade of type 
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks this helps, however, I just realized any middleware component will not be able to refer to this class ProductDTO.GetResponse, since its a method, and not a class, I will check though, and HasError and Error will always be null or not filled in,